# I keep getting console error for a function that is defined onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to write a code editor and I keep running into a supposedly undefined function.

From the HTML file:

```
<button type="button" id="launchButton" onclick="launch();">Launch</button>
```

From JS:

```
function launch() {
"use strict";

var CSSText = document.getElementById('CSS').value;
var HTMLText = document.getElementById('HTML').value;

var head = "<head><style>" + CSSText + "</style></head>";

var iframe = document.getElementById('previewPane');

iframe = (iframe.contentWindow) ? iframe.contentWindow : (iframe.contentDocument.document) ? iframe.contentDocument.document : iframe.contentDocument;
iframe.document.open();
iframe.document.write(head + HTMLText);
iframe.document.close();
return false;
}
launch();
```

And the same keeps happening with two other functions I'm trying to execute:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="CSS" name="CSS" placeholder="Type your CSS here!" rows="10" cols="40" ondblclick="replaceText1();"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
function replaceText1() {
"use strict";

var textAreaObject = document.getElementById('CSS');
textAreaObject.value = "h3 {color: blue; } p { font-family: cursive, arial; font-size: 25pt;}"
}
replaceText1();
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="HTML" name="HTML" placeholder="Type your HTML here!" rows="10" cols="40" ondblclick="replaceText2();"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
function replaceText2() {
"use strict";

var textAreaObject = document.getElementById('HTML');
textAreaObject.value = "<h3> Hello! </h3> <p> applied? </p>"
}
replaceText2();
```

Regardless of anything I've tried, I keep getting Uncaught ReferenceError's at the lines where I call the functions in HTML. What am I not getting from the syntax?

**EDIT**

Here is my HTML document:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title id="titleTag">code editor</title>
    <script href="JS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css"/>
    </head>
<body>

    <h1>Code Editor</h1>

    <div id="center">

        <div class="grid">

            <form action="#" method="post">

                <textarea id="CSS" name="CSS" placeholder="Type your CSS here!" rows="10" cols="40" ondblclick="replaceText1();"></textarea> 

                <br/>

                <textarea id="HTML" name="HTML" placeholder="Type your HTML here!" rows="10" cols="40" ondblclick="replaceText2();"></textarea>

                <br/>

                <button type="button" id="launchButton" onclick="launch();">Launch</button>
                <button type="button" id="clearButton" onclick="clear();">Clear</button>
                <button type="button" id="toggleButton" onclick="toggle();">Toggle</button>

            </form>

        </div>

        <div class="grid">

            <iframe id="previewPane"></iframe>

        </div>
    </div>

    <h2>Zeo</h2>

</body>
```

And the JS file accompanying it:

```
function launch(CSS, HTML, previewPane) {
"use strict";

var CSSText = document.getElementById('CSS').value;
var HTMLText = document.getElementById('HTML').value;

var head = "<head><style>" + CSSText + "</style></head>";

var iframe = document.getElementById('previewPane');

iframe = (iframe.contentWindow) ? iframe.contentWindow : (iframe.contentDocument.document) ? iframe.contentDocument.document : iframe.contentDocument;
iframe.document.open();
iframe.document.write(head + HTMLText);
iframe.document.close();
return false;
}
launch();

function replaceText1() {
"use strict";

var textAreaObject = document.getElementById('CSS');
textAreaObject.value = "h3 {color: blue; } p { font-family: cursive, arial; font-size: 25pt;}"
}
replaceText1();

function replaceText2() {
"use strict";

var textAreaObject = document.getElementById('HTML');
textAreaObject.value = "<h3> Hello! </h3> <p> applied? </p>"
}
replaceText2();
```

Comment: Which line **exactly** causes the error?

Comment: @MattWay The HTML lines I posted return the Uncaught ReferenceError in console when I try to click or doubleclick the objects.

Comment: sounds like it is each of the onclick handlers. There is sooo much to wonder about here. Would like to see the actual code and not JS here and HTML there.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I updated with the full HTML and JS files

Comment: Any errors in the console **before** you click?

Comment: @JaromandaX No, there are no errors when I refresh the page and console.

Comment: are you sure? because your javascript calls `launch` (and other functions) when it loads ... but those `getElementById(...).value`'s will fail because those elements don't yet exist! So, the code you presented **will** show errors on load. The fact that you say there are no errors, suggests the code in the question is not the code you are having an issue with. besides that, I don't think you'll have much luck accessing the `document` in the iframe anyway - because the iframe is not same origin

Comment: @JaromandaX The JS functions aren't supposed to/don't attempt execution until the event of click/doubleclick, so why should they fail on load immediately? And also, if I'm attempting access/update to the HTML document located within the iFrame on the page, how would I do so if not by document?

Comment: because you call `launch();` (line 17)... and `replaceText1();` (line 25) ... and `replaceText2();` (line 33) ... in the JS - you can't see that? you must be looking at your real file

Comment: Your script is never running. The script tag should have a `src` attribute not an `href`.